# Error: Support for running under Java 16 requires Gradle 7, which will be supported in ForgeGradle 5

Tags: java, gradle, forge

Я использую эту документацию-> https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/
(forge documentation)

сейчас я на этом пункте:

> Generating IDE Launch/Run Configurations:

> For IntelliJ, run the genIntellijRuns gradle task (gradlew genIntellijRuns).

Вот ошибка, появляющаяся у меня:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\T\Desktop\mods\Dcraft\build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Dcraft'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'.
   > Found java version 17.0.1. Versions 16 and newer are not supported yet.
     Note: Support for running under Java 16 requires Gradle 7, which will be supported in ForgeGradle 5.
```

line 10 in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
```

Я уже пытался найти ответ на мой вопрос и загружал jdk 15.0.2, но это не помогло...
Я думаю, что ForgeGradle 5 поможет мне, но я не смог понять как его устанавливать.
Пожалуйста, помогите найти решение.

PS. У меня последняя версия java, jdk 17.0.1, gradle 7 и forge mdk 1.16.5-36.1.20

Comment: переведите пожалуйста ваш вопрос на русский язык, или задайте его на соответствующей языковой версии сайта

Comment: Мы должны лазить по переводчикам? Переведите, пожалуйста, вопрос. Please translate this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановка jdk на 15.0.2 помогла решить проблему.